# Can't add foreign key constraint to pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

## Background:

I am building an application with Laravel for coaches to record their sport team's matches during a season. Currently, I am trying to create a pivot table, to map a `Team` to a `Round` (match).

## Relationship overview:

A `User` has one `Team`, but the foreign key to the `user` table from the `team` table (`user_id`) is `nullable`, as an admin will create many `Team`s, but the `user_id` for a `Team` will be assigned at a later date.

A `Team` belongs to a `User` (coach).

There is a many to many relationship between a `Round` and a `Team` (this is where the pivot table comes in).

To map a `Team` to a `Round`, I have a `round_team` table with two foreign keys: `round_id` and `team_id`.

When trying to create the foreign key (`team_id`) on the `round_team` table, I get an error in the console, (after running `php artisan migrate`):

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `round_team` add constraint `round_team_team_id_foreign` foreign key (`team_id`) references `teams` (`id`))


[PDOException]                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I am assuming that this is somehow due to the `teams`.`id` being `nullable`... If this is the case, how do I go about adding this constraint successfully? Otherwise, what is causing the error?

## Migrations:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->enum('role', ['coach', 'admin'])->default('coach');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });


Schema::create('rounds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('round_team', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('round_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('team_id')->unisigned();
        $table->timestamp('date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('round_id')->references('id')->on('rounds');
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
    });
```

Comment: many times this kind of error is because you have records in the db that has blank foreign value. all the round_team records have an valid team_id ??

Comment: Database is completely empty.

Comment: i think it is a typo on `$table->integer('team_id')->unisigned();`, unstead of unsigned

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right. Thank you!